# inserting datas into two or more table

Tags: sql, oracle, loader

I have a question regarding inserting data to ORACLE table with SQL LOADER  into two or more tables
but the error is showing like this,

```
SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 22.
Expecting keyword INTO, found keyword append.
APPEND INTO TABLE "FABRICATION"
^

Loader is finished
```

and the CTL File is ,

```
-- THIS IS TO LOAD DATA INTO MASTER_DRAWING
LOAD DATA
INFILE "C:\Component Folder\POWERHOUSEASSYLIST.csv" 
BADFILE "POWERHOUSEASSYLIST.bad" 
DISCARDFILE "POWERHOUSEASSYLIST.dsc"

APPEND INTO TABLE "MASTER_DRAWING"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
HEAD_MARK,
PROJECT_NAME,
QTY,
COMP_TYPE,
PROFILE,
LENGTH,
SURFACE,
WEIGHT,
REV_DATE "SYSDATE",
REV_NO "1"
)

APPEND INTO TABLE "FABRICATION"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
( 
HEAD_MARK,
PROJECT_NAME,
ID,
MARKING "0",
CUTTING "0",
ASSEMBLY "0",
WELDING "0",
DRILLING "0",
FINISHING "0",
REV_DATE "SYSDATE",
)
```

Please help me what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You had some minor mistakes.

1. `APPEND INTO TABLE "FABRICATION"` does not need the `append`;
2. There was a comma after `REV_DATE "SYSDATE",` which was incorrect.

   ```
   LOAD DATA
   INFILE "C:\Component Folder\POWERHOUSEASSYLIST.csv" 
   BADFILE "POWERHOUSEASSYLIST.bad" 
   DISCARDFILE "POWERHOUSEASSYLIST.dsc"

   APPEND
   INTO TABLE "MASTER_DRAWING"
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
   ( 
   HEAD_MARK,
   PROJECT_NAME,
   QTY,
   COMP_TYPE,
   PROFILE,
   LENGTH,
   SURFACE,
   WEIGHT,
   REV_DATE "SYSDATE",
   REV_NO "1"
   )

   INTO TABLE "FABRICATION"
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
   ( 
   HEAD_MARK,
   PROJECT_NAME,
   ID,
   MARKING "0",
   CUTTING "0",
   ASSEMBLY "0",
   WELDING "0",
   DRILLING "0",
   FINISHING "0",
   REV_DATE "SYSDATE"
   )
   ```